# How to extract values from string with its formatted mask in Ruby

Tags: ruby

We can do it in Ruby: `"I have %{amount} %{food}" % {amount: 5, food: 'apples'}` to get "I have 5 apples". Is there common way for the inverse transformation: using "I have 5 apples" and "I have %{amount} %{food}" to get `{amount: 5, food: 'apples'}`?

Comment: That's called a regex.

Comment: @DaveNewton, is there a way to use %{} syntax with regex?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although you can do named captures, and converting to a named-capture regex with (relatively simple) templating strings shouldn't be *too* hard... but likely not worth it. What's the ultimate problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I parse an HTML and want to have some string in the config, which could be used both for searching it in the page and extract variable values from found strings. Something like `http://some.site/event/%{id}`. I can search for events on the page with `CONFIG[:event_link] % {id: ''}`, but don't know how to use it for extracting id of found events.

Comment: Are all the things you need to look for the same? Or are they arbitrary? There's no "going back" from most/all string templating systems that I'm aware of, although some may provide an AST of the template, which would make it (somewhat) easier to automagically create the corresponding regex. IIRC there are also systems that'll let you provide sample input and create a "parser" out of it, but I don't know of any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

```
def doit(s1, s2)
  a1 = s1.split 
  a2 = s2.split
  a2.each_index.with_object({}) do |i,h|
    word = a2[i][/(?<=%\{).+(?=\})/]
    h[word.to_sym] = a1[i] unless word.nil?
  end.transform_values { |s| s.match?(/\A\-?\d+\z/) ? s.to_i : s }
end
```

```
s1 = "I have 5 apples"
s2 = "I have %{amount} %{food}"
doit(s1, s2)
  #=> {:amount=>5, :food=>"apples"} 

s1 = "223 parcels were delivered last month"
s2 = "%{number} parcels were %{action} last %{period}"
doit(s1, s2)
  #=> {:number=>223, :action=>"delivered", :period=>"month"}
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters (`.+`), immediately preceded by `"%{"` (`(?<=%\{)` being a *positive lookbehind*) and immediately followed by `"}"` (`(?=\})` being a *positive lookahead*).

Comment: Great thanks! It's not a «common way» I looked for, but it definitely does the job and may be very useful for similar situations.

Comment: One fix though: the last regex for converting a string to an integer should be this one: `/\A\-?\d+\z/`

Comment: Michael, the minus sign need only be escaped within a *character class* to avoid it being interpreted as denoting a range. For example, `'-'.match? /[a-z]/
 #=> false`, `'-'.match? /[a\-z]/ #=> true`. Moreover, if a minus sign appears at the beginning or end of the character class it need not be escaped because it obviously would not denote a range: `'-'.match? /[-ab]/ #=> true`, `'-'.match? /[ab-]/ #=true`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. But I added a backslash before **d**, not before **minus**. So, the right regexp should be `/\A-?\d+\z/`, right?

Comment: That's correct. I don't know what happened to the backslash before `d`. It obviously was there when I executed the method. Thanks for the catch. Your second comment has a backslash before the minus sign as well, which is what caught my eye.

Answer (score 0):

If the substrings are separated with spaces, you could find the corresponding regex with [named captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures):

```
text = "I have 5 apples"
# "I have %{amount} %{food}"
format = /\AI have (?<amount>\S+) (?<food>\S+)\z/

p text.match(format).named_captures
# {"amount"=>"5", "food"=>"apples"}
```

You didn't show any code, so I'll leave it as an exercise to transform the `"I have %{amount} %{food}"` string into the `/\AI have (?<amount>\S+) (?<food>\S+)\z/` regex.